# Azcopy failed to remove file

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

I'm using Jenkins with azcopy (10.5.0) command for upload and remove files on Azure Storage account (Containers)

Previously i can use as properly. But now i found problem about failed to remove files.

Before i remove file.
I use 'azcopy list' to list all file in folder. It will show that have 3 files in folders

[image: Show3 Files]

Then i use 'azcopy rm' to remove all file in folder.

```
azcopy rm https://xxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/xxx/xxx    --recursive=true
```

It will show 4 files to remove. I don't know where the additional file came from.
And this task will failed.

[image: Remove 4 Files]

Next, I'm trying to do it again.
When list the file. It don't have any more file in that folder.

[image: No more file]

But in remove file step it still show 1 file to remove. But this time it can remove successful.

[image: Remove 1 file]

I don't know where the additional file came from.
Does it have any Hidden file?

Please help suggest.
Thank you.